# How to create a new object using a class name in Java ME?

Tags: java-me

So far I couldn't find a method which doesn't require the Constructor class.

This class is not available in Java ME.

Is there any other way?

Note that the class's constructor takes parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
String className = "java.lang.String";
Class theClass = Class.forName(className);
// this line will call the empty constructor
String s = (String) theClass.newInstance();
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29

Comment: I should have probably made it clear that the class's takes parameters, otherwise your solution would have worked.

Comment: If you can not add an empty constructor for the class, it can not be instantiated. :(